# Lucene search, word separator unaware

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I have list of words for example:

```
'today
today
t-oday
t oday
t/oda y
```

How can I retrieve all these words from a Lucene index if I search on the words `today` or `t/oday` or `'today`.

I actually want the search to be insensitive to ampersand, dash, space and some other characters.

What's is the best way to deal with this situation? Should I write my own analyzer/tokenizer or is there something I can use to perform this search?

I'm using Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `CharFilter` to your analyzer would probably be the best solution.  This allows you to preprocess the input, before even the tokenizer is applied.  There are some TokenFilter examples in the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html/search-mapping.html#d0e3461) (see example 4.13).

I'd recommend using a [`MappingCharFilterFactory`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory), and define mapping to strip the characters you aren't interested in.

Stripping all the spaces from the input seems a rather unusual case to me, since that will likely prevent useful tokenization, but I suppose I'll assume you have taken that into consideration.